# Python 2.7: Read file with Chinese characters

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, character, filenames

I am trying to analyze data within CSV files with Chinese characters in their names (E.g. "粗1 25g"). 
I am using Tkinter to choose the files like so:

```
selectedFiles = askopenfilenames(filetypes=[("xlsx","*"),("xls","*")]) # Utilize Tkinker dialog window to choose files
selectedFiles = master.tk.splitlist(selectedFiles) # Create list from files chosen
```

I have attempted to convert the filename to unicode in this way:

```
selectedFiles = [x.decode("utf-8") for x in selectedFiles]
```

Only to yield the error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xb4 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I have also tried converting the filenames as the files are created with the following:

```
titles = [x.encode('utf-8') for x in titles]
```

Only to receive the error:

```
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('wb') or filename: 'C:\...\\data_division_files\\\xe7\xb2\x971 25g.csv'
```

I have also tried combinations of the above methods to no avail. 
What can I do to allow these files to be read in Python?

(This question,while related, has not been able to solve my problem: [Obtain File size with os.path.getsize() in Python 2.7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17410628/obtain-file-size-with-os-path-getsize-in-python-2-7-5))

Comment: You have to know, which encoding is used for your filenames.
Judging from your error message, it may be utf16. Try filename.decode("utf16")

Comment: import codecs and then use proper methods of codecs on chinese filename text.

import codecs

Comment: @NileshG: `codecs` is for Unicode _contents_; it doesn't do any good for Unicode _filenames_.

Comment: @abarnert: Filename is nothing but a text... So we can use codecs ...

Comment: I think the problem lies in the naming of the files in the first place. If I change the elements of the list of files I have selected, then those files don't exist. I must instead make sure the original filenames are readable by the askopenfilenames function and other functions I am performing on them.

Comment: @nichosukiennik: No. For strings, you just call `encode` or `decode`, not `codecs.open`.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `decode` on a `unicode` object, it first encodes it with `sys.getdefaultencoding()` so it can decode it for you. Which is why you get an error about ASCII even though you didn't ask for ASCII anywhere.

So, where are you getting a `unicode` object from? From `askopenfilename`. From a quick test, it looks like it always returns `unicode` values on Windows (presumably by getting the UTF-16 and decoding it), while on POSIX it returns some `unicode` and some `str` (I'd guess by leaving alone anything that fits into 7-bit ASCII, decoding anything else with your filesystem encoding). If you'd tried printing out the repr or type or anything of `selectedFiles`, the problem would have been obvious.

---

Meanwhile, the `encode('utf-8')` shouldn't cause any `UnicodeError`s… but it's likely that your filesystem encoding isn't UTF-8 on Windows, so it will probably cause a lot of `IOError`s with errno 2 (trying to open files that don't exist, or to create files in directories that don't exist), 21 (trying to open files with illegal file or directory names on Windows), etc. And it looks like that's exactly what you're seeing. And there's really no reason to do it; just pass the pathnames as-is to `open` and they'll be fine.

---

So, basically, if you removed all of your `encode` and `decode` calls, your code would probably just work.

However, there's an even easier solution: Just use `askopenfile` or `asksaveasfile` instead of `askopenfilename` or `asksaveasfilename`. Let Tk figure out how to use its pathnames and just hand you the file objects, instead of messing with the pathnames yourself.

Comment: When I print selectedFiles after using `decode('utf-8')` I get `[u'C:/.../data_division_files/\u7c973 25g.csv']`. When I use `utf-16` I get a new error: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf16' codec can't decode byte 0x76 in position 54: truncated data` and selectedfiles comes out as `('C:/.../data_division_files/\xe5\x8e\x9f\xe6\xa0\xb7  25g.csv',)`. The code does not simply work  without any encoding/decoding, and askopenfiles brings up a new error: `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'{'`

Comment: @nichosukiennik: I wanted you to print out `selectedFiles` without doing _anything_ to it, just exactly what `askopenfilename` returned.

Comment: @nichosukiennik: Meanwhile, if `askopenfile` doesn't work, maybe the problem is that Python is guessing your filesystem encoding wrong (or, worse, your filesystem doesn't have a consistent encoding). What does `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` say?

Comment: `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` gave me `cp936` at first, and next time I tried gave me `mbcs`. selectedFiles without doing anything gives me `File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\_datasource.py", line 479, in open
    raise IOError("%s not found." % path)
IOError: C:/Users/nsukiennik/data_division_files/粗2 25g.csv not found.
Exception in Tkinter callback`. Maybe an issue with Tkinter then?

Comment: @nichosukiennik: Wow, sounds like something is very strange about your setup. If Python can't figure out what charset it's getting back from your filesystem, the only option is to do it manually, which is painful. (Later versions of python use the Windows UTF-16 APIs more and the OEM code page APIs less, but (a) you may not be able to upgrade to 3.x, and (b) I don't know if tkinter has been updated anyway. Anyway, two options:

Comment: If you only care about this computer, figure out through trial and error whether it's using cp936 or something else, then hardcore that either as your filesystemencoding, or as a variable that you pass to .decode for every name you get from the filesystem and to .encode for every name you pass to it.

Comment: Or, use pywin32 and its win32api or win32file module to make calls like CreateFileW or _wopen instead of using nice Python file objects.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'll post here if anything works.