# os.walk() generates invalid paths for files with accented letters on Windows 10

Tags: python, python-2.7, windows-10

I'm trying to run a function that returns the total size of a folder and all of its content.
this is the function:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8-*-

import os


def get_size(start_path = '.'):
    total_size = 0
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(start_path):
        for f in filenames:
            fp = os.path.join(dirpath, f)
            # skip if it is symbolic link
            if not os.path.islink(fp):
                total_size += os.path.getsize(fp)

    return total_size
```

The function works fine with any path as an input, except when I'm giving it a path of a folder that has a file with accented letters on its name on it.

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Owner/PycharmProjects/test/tester.py", line 18, in <module>
    print get_size("c:\\nizan\\kal")
  File "C:/Users/Owner/PycharmProjects/test/tester.py", line 13, in get_size
    total_size += os.path.getsize(fp)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\genericpath.py", line 49, in getsize
    return os.stat(filename).st_size
WindowsError: [Error 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label  
syntax is incorrect: 'c:\\nizan\\kal\\?xample.txt'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

The real name of the file that is causing the problem is "éxample.txt".
I have tried using decode like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49808200/12770136).
but it didn't work.

Comment: Which operating system and version are you running? (Windows uses UTF-16 for its Unicode-aware APIs, whereas UNIX-y systems generally treat filenames as bytestrings, not Unicode strings, and leave translation to or from multi-byte strings to the application layer).

Comment: I'm using windows 10

Comment: It is indeed genuinely wrong for there to be a `?` literal there. Can you verify that the `?` is present, as a literal, in the `filenames` list returned from `os.walk()`, just so we can be 100% certain that it's not one of the `os.path` functions that's doing that? (That way the question/problem could be narrowed down specifically to the content returned by `os.walk()`).

Comment: (I don't have any Windows machines on-hand, so can't reproduce myself; this works perfectly well on MacOS or Linux).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I printed the filenames list returned from the os.walk() and the '?' was already there

Comment: Good, then -- that confirms the title I edited in is accurate. Will need to let someone with more knowledge about Windows step in to build an actual answer.

Comment: Can you try prefixing the string `'.'` with `u`, so `u'.'`? Unicode inputs should return Unicode outputs I've read, though it works just fine on my computer without it.

Comment: @iliketodropstuff Your code works just fine here on Windows 10.